# React + .NET Core Web API, Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to do a login,register page with React, and i'm using the JWT for authentication.
my backend is working correctly,i have tested it on Postman and it works.

but when i'm started the build frontend i have a error.

and my code is :

```
 import { METHODS } from "http";
 import React, { SyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
 const Register = () => {
 const [FirstName,setName ] = useState('');
 const [LastName,setLastName ] = useState('');
 const [Email,setEmail ] = useState('');
 const [Password,setPassword ] = useState('');
 const submit  = async (e:SyntheticEvent) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 const response = await fetch ('http://localhost:44385/api/auth/register' , {
 method:'POST',
 headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
 body: JSON.stringify( {
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Email,
    Password
  })
})
 const content = await response.json();
console.log(content);

}
return (
<form onSubmit={submit}>

<h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Register</h1>

<input  className="form-control"  placeholder="FirstName" required
onChange={e=> setName(e.target.value)} />

<input  className="form-control"  placeholder="Last Name" required
onChange={e=> setLastName(e.target.value)} />

<input type="email" className="form-control"  
  placeholder="name@example.com" required 
 onChange={e=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>

<input type="password" className="form-control"  placeholder="******" 
  required 
onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>

 <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
   type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
);
};

 export default Register;
```

error:[image: errorpic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:44385",
```

to your React project's **package.json**

I would also suggest enclosing your fetch in a `try/catch` block.